# grails spring security rest log out logging

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

I'm trying to logging security based on `spring-security-rest` plugin in Grails.
For log in, i have no problem, but when i try to log out, i can't log it out in any way and any method i found in stackoverflow like implementing `LogoutHandler` or `ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent>` not help either...

here's part of my code

```
class SecurityLogger implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent>, LogoutHandler {

@Override
void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
    println 'LOGGED OUT!!!'
}

@Override
void logout(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) {
    println 'LOGGED OUT!!!'
}
```

my `resource.groovy`

```
beans = {
    securityLogger(SecurityLogger)
}
```

and my `config.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames =
        ['rememberMeServices',
         'securityContextLogoutHandler',
         'securityLogger']
```

How can i get the log for log out and session expired in Grails spring security rest? Thanks in advance :)